# How do I mock values returned in a method parameter?

Tags: parameters, mockito, mybatis

I’m using Mockito 1.9.5.  How do I mock a return value coming from a parameter passed to a method?  I have this method …

```
String createStuff(final Map<String, Object> params);
```

This is the interface for a MyBatis (v 3.3.0).  Basically, I pass in some params into the map, and the map returns those params in addition to other values.  How do I mock what the Map is after the call?

If it is relevant, below is the mapping file for which this method is an interface to:

```
<mapper namespace="org.mainco.myproject.repo.MyInterface">

<select id="createStuff” parameterType="java.util.HashMap" 
    statementType="CALLABLE">
    { call CreateStuff (
        #{param1, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
        #{param2, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{outParam, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    )} 
</select>

</mapper>
```

Comment: Use a Mockito `Answer` object to pick up the parameter object and make whatever changes you need to make to it.  See if you can figure it out from http://googletesting.blogspot.co.nz/2014/03/whenhow-to-use-mockito-answer.html - if not, post again and I'll try to post something more detailed.

Comment: That solved it, thanks.